# Unable to access data from array inside foreach loop - Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, arrayobject

My DB has 2 rows of values : `Test2 campaign` & `premium dove`

**view page**

```
foreach ($estedit as $estrow) { 
                 //print_r($estrow);
                 echo $estrow->name;
                              }
```

The above code shows these 2 values at the bottom as in the below linked image, but it displays error `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`.

Error Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7wtz.png

`print_r($estrow);` inside the `foreach` loop shows the below given data:

`stdClass Object ( [est_id] => 3 [name] => Test2 campaign ) stdClass Object ( [est_id] => 1 [name] => premium dove )`.

Accessing the `name` field as `$estrow->name` shows the error `Illegal string offset 'name'`.
What am i doing wrong?
How can i access the `name` field here ?

**Controller**

```
 $estedit[] = '';

                    foreach ($est_id as $item) {

                        $estedit[] = $this->Report->get_estedit($item);

                        $estlineedit[] = $this->Report->get_estline_edit($item);
                    }
                    $data['estedit'] = $estedit;
                    $data['estlineedit'] = $estlineedit;
                    $data['date'] = $date;
                    $this->load->view('reports/download_report_view', $data);
```

Comment: I belive you are reassign `$estedit` somewhere inside `foreach` loop

Comment: @Anton No. i didn't

Comment: @Anton see the update dquestion body. i've added my controller code portion from where am passing this data to view

Comment: It makes no sense that this would show the values you are after in the first place, if it could not access them. _"print_r($estrow); inside the foreach loop shows the below given data"_ - okay, but that does not necessarily mean, that the error comes from the same loop iterations, in which you are getting this debug output. `print_r(null)` or `print_r(false)` for example result in absolutely no visible output - so if you had more items in `$estedit` than you thought maybe, and one of them was null or false, that would absolutely explain what you are seeing.

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, that is a better debug tool. And use it to check what `$estedit` contains, instead of trying to figure out what is going on only inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set empty string as first element of `$estedit`

```
 $estedit[] = '';
```

Looks like you want

```
 $estedit = [];
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$estedit = array();
```

Or this:

```
$estedit = [];
```

Instead of:

```
$estedit[] = '';
```